# Hide StockGraph in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts

I use amcharts library and I draw some StockGraphs on stockPanel and I want to allow show and hide any graph on the panel by cheeking/uncheeking check box. How could I show and hide StockGraph in amcharts?

Answer (score 0):

You can show or hide single graphs by using the functions [hideGraph()](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmCoordinateChart#hideGraph) or [showGraph()](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmCoordinateChart#showGraph).
You need to pass the graph as parameter. (it has to be an AmGraph object)